# Get JSON stored in a HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have JSON within a HTML element on page that I get using PHP

```
echo "<div id='json'>" . json_encode($response) . "</div>";
```

I want to using jQuery simply to log the data to the console (for now) but the only response I get is:

```
Object { }
```

Here is my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var data = jQuery("#json").data();      
    console.log(data);
});
```

and a sample JSON data response

```
{
"posts":{
  "attributes":{
     "dfp_post":3,
     "dfp_shortcode":"[dfp_ads id=1383]",
     "wildcard_pos":5,
     "wildcard_shortcode":"[widget id='wp_widget-46']",
     "twitter_id":"@TeamName",
     "twitter_pos":8,
     "facebook_id":"teamname",
     "facebook_pos":5
  },
  "0":{
     "post":{
        "id":3945,
        "pub_date":"2016-05-30 00:00:00",
        "title":"Trio to tour on back of Twickenham win",
        "excerpt":""
     }
  },
```

Comment: Why you don't use `text()` instead of `data()`.

Comment: why don't you 'store' that json as a js-var in first place? would be much easier! storing data in html is not a goood choice...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get JSON content and then parse it using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**. The **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** method returns object of all `data-*` attribute values not the text data.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(jQuery("#json").text());      
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Oh dear. What a waste of Stack Overflow resources. `.text()` not get `data()` silly me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although the given answer solves your problem, I wanna give you a different answer:

It would be better to store that json directry as javascript var. First you don't have to fetch it later, second it's never the best choice to store data in html-elements.

So I'd recommend doing this:

```
echo "<script>jsonData=" . json_encode($response) . ";</script>";
```

Then there's no need to fetch and convert it from a string from a html....

later you can access it (anywhere after you've declared it):

```
<script>
   console.log(jsonData);
</script>
```

Comment: I definitely agree that I should be doing this and not printing out to a hidden HTML element. However, now I get this in the console `Object { posts: Object }`

Comment: You can also use console.dir(data) to see more of an object.

Comment: You can click on the 'Object' inside posts, it will open that then (at least in chrome).